# Criar atributo único além da Chave Primária em code-first

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, code-first

Estou criando uma tabela de `Logradouro` onde o campo `CEP` não é a chave primária, mas deve ser único.
Como faço isso usando ***code-first*** no **Entity 6.0**?

Para criar chave primárias eu uso o método [`HasKey`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591617.aspx#1.1):

```
ToTable("Logradouros").HasKey(x => x.LogradouroId);
```

Vi que neste método é possível usar mais de um campo criando chave composta. Se o `CEP` precisa ser único e indexado ele deve ser chave da tabela também?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pode usar o [Index]

```
[Index(IsUnique = true)] 
[StringLength(200)] 
public string Username { get; set; }
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591583.aspx#Index

Se tiver a usar o modelBuilder, use assim:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
    .HasIndex("IX_Username",          // Provide the index name.
        e => e.Property(x => x.Username))  // Multiple columns as desired.
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22618237/how-to-create-index-in-entity-framework-6-2-with-code-first

Comment: De acordo com os links a primeira solução só funciona a partir do `Entity 6.1` e a segunda é relativa ao `Entity 6.2`, eu preciso de uma que funciona no `Entity 6.0` (editei minha pergunta para especificar isso)...

Comment: mas qual o problema o 6.1 e o 6.0 tem apis muito semelhantes você pode fazer o update simples pelo nuget

Comment: Atualizei o Entities e a primeira solução funcionou bem, obrigado!